# Sum of a series of integrals of increasing order

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I have a series and I am wondering under what conditions of $g(t)$ does it converge, and what does it converge to?

$$ \lambda \int_{0}^{x}g(t) \, dt + \lambda^2 \int_{0}^{x} \int_{0}^{t} g(t_1) \, dt_1\, dt + \lambda^3 \int_{0}^{x} \int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{t_1} g(t_2)  \, dt_2 \,dt_1\, dt +  \cdots $$

I also have $0 < x < 1$. Can I be pointed in the direction of any useful theorems for finding this series. I am trying to understand solutions to the Volterra equation when the kernel is $1$.

Comment: Did you mean $0 < \lambda < 1$? Also, to figure out what the series $S(x)$ converges to (under the assumption that it does), differentiate term by term (assuming this is valid) to get $S'(x) = \lambda g(x) + \lambda S(x)$. What does this tell you about the series $S(x)$? What conditions are needed for this to work?

Comment: Unless the broader question I am seeking to solve is ill-posed I mean $0 < x < 1$. However I just updated the lower integration bound so it probably makes more sense now.

Comment: Also thanks for the line of thinking, I will chew on it for a bit.